# System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute namespace is modified unexpectedly when added to XElement

Tags: .net, xml, linq, f#

The namespace of my XAttribute is being modified unexpectedly when added to a parent XElement.

I have some F# code that looks like this:

```ml
let myRoot = XElement(XName.Get("MyRoot"))
let mychildxelement = XElement(XName.Get("MyXElement"))
myRoot.Add(mychildxelement)
myRoot.Add(XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "odata", "http://mynamespace"))
let name = XNamespace.Get("odata") + myattrname
mychildxelement.Add(XAttribute(name, "false"))
```

Unfortunately, when I print out myRoot (`myRoot.ToString()`), it generates the following xml:

```
<MyRoot xmlns:odata="http://mynamespace">
  <MyXElement p3:myattrname="false" xmlns:p3="odata" />
</MyRoot>
```

For some reason it's changing the namespace to "p3" and adding an extra namespace shortcut at the root level of the XElement. I really want to avoid the Element level xmlns. Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML doesn't allow arbitrary prefixes without defining them. When you have no parent element or containing document, the only place the namespace declaration can go is the element itself. You can customise the prefix however:

```ml
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

open System.Xml.Linq

let myAttrName = "myattrname"
let odata = "odata"
let name = XNamespace.Get(odata) + myAttrName
let myXElement = XElement(XName.Get("MyXElement"))
myXElement.Add(XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + odata, odata))
myXElement.Add(XAttribute(name, "false"))

myXElement.ToString()
// "<MyXElement xmlns:odata="odata" odata:myattrname="false" />"
```

**Update**

When you have a parent element, the namespace for the child needs to be specified as follows (i.e. use the namespace and not its prefix):

```ml
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

open System.Xml.Linq

let odata = XNamespace.Xmlns + "odata"
let odataNS = "http://mynamespace"
let myRoot = XElement(XName.Get("MyRoot"))
myRoot.Add(XAttribute(odata, odataNS))

let myChildXElement = XElement(XName.Get("MyXElement"))
myChildXElement.Add(XAttribute(XNamespace.Get(odataNS) + "myAttrName", "false"))
myRoot.Add(myChildXElement)

printfn "%A" myRoot
```

which prints (syntax highlighting by SO)

```ml
<MyRoot xmlns:odata="http://mynamespace">
  <MyXElement odata:myAttrName="false" />
</MyRoot>
```

Comment: Thanks this helps me understand what's going on. Unfortunately, there is a parent element that sets the xmlns and I still get the same result. Do you have an idea about what I'm missing? (I've updated original question to include the code with the root element)